# What is the future of App Data folder in google drive?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, app-data

Im working on a game that uses google drive android api to store save games into app data folder. Now i want to migrate everything to REST api, since gdrive android api is deprecated now, but i noticed very strange statement in deprecation notice here: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/deprecation

"Support for storing and syncing in the app data folder will likely be removed from Drive in the future. Clients requiring app data storage are strongly encouraged to migrate to a non-Drive solution such as Cloud Firestore."

Anybody knows more concrete timeline for app data deprecation apart from "will likely be removed"?

Question is if it's still reasonable to invest time to migrate savegame storage to rest api or to just switch to Cloud Firestore as suggested.

Comment: cant u save game saves to local device? and/if the user gets a new device, you can also create a user account and save it on a DB.

Comment: Hi, do you have progress on this issue as it has happened 1 year ago, but the answer seems not clear yet. For example, the Google Play Service examples in github still use the Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER to work (deprecated). Their documentation states some things, but their examples speak other things. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you just need to use the new version of the Google Drive Android API https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/appdata

Comment: This does not address the question - the thing which is *explicitly* deprecated is the non-REST API; the thing which is apparently just "likely" to be removed is the application data folder. There is plenty of information about the first, but none about the second.